# What is the maximum length for a Windows XP hostname?

Tags: windows, hostname

I intend to rename several machines to be more detailed about their location.

The trouble is that I don't know exactly how long of a hostname is allowed.

What is the maximum length for a Windows XP hostname?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

NETBIOS limits the name length to 15 characters.  You give the computer a longer hostname (which is fine with Active Directory since it uses DNS, not NETBIOS) but the NETBIOS name will be truncated.

This [KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909264) lists the limits, which shows 15 chargers for NETBIOS names and 24 for Active Directory host names.

Comment: This just solved my multi-day debugging of why I couldn't mount my Samba NAS. Thanks!

Comment: I just want to add some error text so Google can index it as this was the problem my co-workers and I were running into.  If you see the following error, your hostname might be too long!_____________________
`SPNEGO login failed: The network responded incorrectly.
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_NETWORK_RESPONSE`